# Delta lake Spark - whenNotMatchedInsert() do nothing

Tags: pyspark, merge, delta-lake

We have a generic delta lake merge code where it has both update and insert in a single execute statement

I have some situation where

1. I need to update the values in table (insert should be blank)
2. I need to insert the values in table

```
##only Update
df_look.alias("dt").merge(
df_o.alias("lt"),
condition="system_id=lt.system_id") \
.whenMatchedUpdate(set ={"dt.update_tmst":current_timestamp(),"active_ind":lit("N")}) \
.whenNotMatchedInsert("DO NOTHING").execute()


##only Insert
df_look.alias("dt").merge(
df_o.alias("lt"),
condition="system_id=lt.system_id") \
.whenMatchedUpdate(set ={"dt.update_tmst":current_timestamp(),"active_ind":lit("Y")}) \
.whenNotMatchedInsert(values={"dt.system_id": col("lt.system_id")).execute()
```

I tried the below option

```
df_look.alias("dt").merge(
df_o.alias("lt"),
condition="dt.system_id=lt.system_id and dt.S4=lt.S4") \
.whenMatchedUpdate(set ={"dt.update_tmst":current_timestamp(),"active_ind":lit("N")}) \
.whenNotMatchedInsert((values={})).execute()
```

I got he below error

*Unable to find the column 'type_cd' of the target table from the INSERT columns: . INSERT clause must specify value for all the columns of the target table*

Is there any way in single statement we can use update and make insert blank and next statement we can use only insert and update condition blank . Will the delta lake supports ?